# wrong calculation by borland builder c++

Tags: date-arithmetic, borland-c++

I'm using Borland BCB6 C++ Builder. My code contains the following computation:

```
float result= (152*pow(cos(80),2)) + (70*pow(sin(80),2));
```

In debug mode, I find that this expression evaluates to about 70.992, whereas [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28152*pow%28cos%2880%29%2C2%29%29%20%2B%20%2870*pow%28sin%2880%29%2C2%29%29) tells me that the value should be about 72.4726.
What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: I think it has something to do with decimal placement in the decimal number. Try using `double` or `long` instead.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Floating-point precision is not the answer, here.

Comment: I just super casted everything, and every time got the exact answer that you are getting. Strange. As one example, tried doubles too. I tested this on http://ideone.com/bXjmGY to see.

Comment: @Spektre do you want to post this as the answer. This makes sense now (can't speak for OP.)

Comment: @EvanCarslake you're right moved to answer

Answer (score 1):

In `math.h` the goniometric functions use radians!!!

- so instead `80.0` [deg] use `80.0*M_PI/180.0` [rad]
- that will convert the angle from degrees to radians
- I also usually define `deg,rad` constants and use them:

  ```
  const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
  const double rad=180.0/M_PI;
  double result= (152.0*pow(cos(80.0*deg),2.0)) + (70.0*pow(sin(80.0*deg),2.0));
  ```